# didUpdateLocations does not get called when app enters foreground, core location, ios

Tags: objective-c, ios5, core-location, viewwillappear

my goal is whenever app enters fore ground, i will fetch the location to update my weather forecast. What I do is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m

}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enterForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
#pragma mark - Click to get weather
-(void)enterForeground {
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
 NSLog@"didUpdateLocations";
}
```

However, `enterForeGround` does get call whenver I enter fore ground but didUpdateLocations doesnot get called all the time. 
I dont know what I am missing some crucial things for location service. Please advice me if you have any ideas. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is never a guarantee that didUpdateLocations will be called. The thing you can do is when viewDidLoad is called, you can request que last location with. self.locationManager.location.

You can now check the timestamp and the precision of that location. If the data is too old or innacurate for your needs, you then call startUpdatingLocation, and when you get a fix according to your filter and accuracy, didUpdateLocations will be called.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add Location Services in background by going to Targets -> Capabilities and under "Background Modes" check on "Location Updates". 
  Secondly you need to start location update [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation] somewhere appropriately (for you code provided above in viewWillAppear seems to be the best choice)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
   [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation]
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(enterForeground) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
```

Now when you app enter background mode and reenter Foreground, the locationManager delegate method should be called.